# How can I overwrite an existing column in a PySpark DataFrame with another column in that DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say, for example, I have the following PySpark DataFrame.

```
>>> pdf = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Mike', 'Sally'], 'AnotherName': ['Chris', 'Carson', 'Joe']})
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
>>> df.show()

+-----+-----------+
| Name|AnotherName|
+-----+-----------+
| John|      Chris|
| Mike|     Carson|
|Sally|        Joe|
+-----+-----------+
```

I would like to overwrite the column `AnotherName` with the values in the `Name` column.  The desired result would be:

```
+-----------+
|AnotherName|
+-----------+
|       John|
|       Mike|
|      Sally|
+-----------+
```

I have tried using both the `DataFrame.withColumn()` method and the `DataFrame.withColumnRenamed()` method and get the following results.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
>>> df = df.withColumn('Name', col('AnotherName'))
>>> df.show()
+-----------+-----------+
|AnotherName|AnotherName|
+-----------+-----------+
|       John|      Chris|
|       Mike|     Carson|
|      Sally|        Joe|
+-----------+-----------+
```

```
>>> df = df.withColumnRenamed('Name', 'AnotherName')
>>> df.show()
+-----------+-----------+
|AnotherName|AnotherName|
+-----------+-----------+
|       John|      Chris|
|       Mike|     Carson|
|      Sally|        Joe|
+-----------+-----------+
```

In both cases, if I `df.drop('AnotherName')`, it drops both columns.

I want to overwrite the existing `AnotherName` column instead of creating an additional `AnotherName` column.  I've read that these methods are supposed to overwrite.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Just drop AnotherName first, then rename "Name" to "AnotherName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a column 'AnotherName' the same as 'Name',and then `drop` 'Name':

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = df.withColumn('AnotherName',col('Name')).drop('Name')

>>> df.show()

+-----------+
|AnotherName|
+-----------+
|       John|
|       Mike|
|      Sally|
+-----------+
```